# Search a word and Get Predictive Search Words from String (not complete string) in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, search, full-text-search, exact-match

I have SQL Table Design like Listed Below

```
*-----------------------------------------
| id | title                              |
| -- | -----------------------------------|
| 1  | This is nice pen looking good      |
| 2  | This is nice pen looking elegent   |
| 3  | This is nice pen looking great     |
| 4  | This is nice pen looking best.     |
------------------------------------------
```

Example Query: `Select * from table where title LIKE '%looking%'`

when i try to search word **"looking"** using **(like query)** or using **(Regular Expressions)** like example query, I am getting complete string results mentioned below

**Results**

```
*------------------------------------
| title                              |
| -----------------------------------|
| This is nice pen looking good      |
| This is nice pen looking elegent   |
| This is nice pen looking great     |
| This is nice pen looking best.     |
-------------------------------------
```

**What i want?**

**I want predective search words (not complete string)**

**How can i get below mentioned Results by searching word (looking) using SQL.**

```
*-------------------
| title             |
| ------------------|
| looking good      |
| looking elegent   |
| looking great     |
| looking best.     |
--------------------
```

Please Suggest how can i write query for geting these types of results?
Thanks

Comment: Please explain what *you* mean by "predictive search words".

Comment: means when i try to search word "looking", i want result of exact match word and next word of searched word.
Searched Word: "looking"
results i want
"looking good"
"looking elegent"
"looking great" etc

Comment: An interesting question, but wrong toolset. Mysql is a database, not a text analytics tool. It does not have the concept of words. You can obviously combine a set of string functions and achieve a close proxy of what you want within mysql, but the performance will be terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first next work using `substring_index()`:

```
Select t.*,
       substring_index(substring_index(concat(' ', title, ' '), ' looking ', -1), ' ', 1) as next-word
from table
where title LIKE '%looking%';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94d78da674a201563bc42a6d638bb6c1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: And I can give you several cases when this solution will not work with real-life text. You are oversimplifying it.